# Wishlist is empty even after adding an item

Tags: magento2, wishlist

If i add an item to wishlist i am getting "the item has been added to your Wish List. Click here to continue shopping." and below this message Am getting this "you have no items in your wish list."

I have tried clearing the cache everything but still not working.

Comment: Please any one help on the above.

Comment: Hi did you solve this?